# Proof of "for composite $n>4, n∣(n−1)!$"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was trying to understand the beautiful Wilson's theorem, and in so doing I was wondering whether this conjecture is true.  Is there any theorem which states something similar to this:

> Every composite number $n>4$ will have all of its prime factors (edit for clarity: and not just distinct prime factors) occur at
>   least once in the representation of $(n-1)!$

i.e.,

> For composite $n>4, n∣(n−1)!$

Please point me to a proof of this statement, if it is true, or a counter-example otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: You mean:  "all of it's prime factors occur at least one *in the representation* of the number (n-1)!"

Comment: @MARXOS Yes. I've fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: You could have just said "for composite $n>4$, $n\mid(n-1)!$".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I've made the change.  I'm new to math, so I am only just starting to learn how to make statements succinct. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the amendment in the comments that all prime factors with duplication appear in $(n-1)!$, this is equivalent to the assertion $n\mid (n-1)!$. There are a few cases to consider:

- If $n$ is prime, of course this does not hold because all the factors of $(n-1)!$ are coprime to $n$.
- If $n$ is not a prime power, then for every $p^k\mid n$, $p^k\le n-1$ so $p^k\mid (n-1)!$.
- If $n=p^k$ and $k>2$, then $p\cdot p^{k-1}\mid (n-1)!$ since $p<p^{k-1}\le n-1$.
- If $n=p^2$ and $p>2$, then $p<2p\le n-1$ implies $n\mid p(2p)\mid(n-1)!$.
- Otherwise, $n=4$. In this case $(n-1)!=6$ so the statement does not hold.

Thus we have proven that an integer $n>1$ satisfies $n\mid (n-1)!$ if and only if $n>4$ and $n$ is composite.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!  I think the first case need not have been considered since the statement explicitly mentions $n$ to be composite, but it nevertheless gives a complete picture.

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ is composite, then its prime factors are all numbers less than $n - 1$, so they are factors of $(n-1)!$.

Comment: I understand that works for distinct prime factors, but a composite number could be made of multiple powers of the same prime factor.  For example,  $2^(200)$.  Is there any proof that all $200$ copies of $2$ will occur at least once in the factorial of the previous number?

Comment: If $p^k$ divides $n$, then it is still a number less than $n - 1$, so it appears in $(n-1)!$.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.  But I was also wondering why this doesn't work for $4$.  Because $3!$ doesn't cover all of the prime factors of $4$.

Comment: @AkashC Good point, I was assuming $n \neq p^k$. If $n = p^k$ then you need to be a little more careful, but you can always find $k$ copies of $p$ for $n > 4$. See Mario's answer.